# How to control MultiThreading in MVP pattern for Android development?

Tags: android, multithreading, mvp

Recently, I try to use `MVP` Pattern in my android project.

I know that I can't do bussiness logic job in `View` layer. `View` must deliver all works to `Presenter` layer then wait for the result from `Presenter`.

`View` should do anything in UI thread. But `Presenter` may do something in `Sub-Thread`.

How do I control MultiThreading in `View` layout and `Preseneter` layer?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You have two directions you need to communicate:

a) non-UI to UI thread

and

b) UI thread to non-UI thread.

For the first case, a popular way these days is to use **runOnUiThread()**

Here's a nice survey of this technique and other popular options:

http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-non-ui-to-ui-thread-communications-part-1-of-5/

As for the other direction, it is not typically necessary unless you have slow blocking operations.  It is more a question of clean organization of your source code. A modern technique for sending results back from View to Presenter is using custom interfaces in Fragments like this in the "Communicating with the Activity" section:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Note that you should not put long running operations on the UI thread because it will make your app feel sluggish.  Try to run them on a different thread if they will take more than 50 milliseconds or so.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I wrote a lot of ` new Thread ().start() ` code to prevent blocking UI thread. I think it was not wise.

Comment: But writing runOnUiThread is so redundant because all of View methods will run on UI thread ... What could I do?

Answer (score 0):

Android already separates the functionality of the UI and the controller (or Presenter). It's really your job to separate it even more to make it follow the MVP pattern stronger. The view is on its own thread separate from your presenters. You won't need to do anymore threading for that unless you'd like to for whatever reason.

When I say separating it farther I just mean implementing a structure that abstracts the handling of data to be able to be reused or changed easily.